# When do I need type annotations?

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass, type-families

Consider these functions

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

tryMe :: Maybe Int -> Int -> Int
tryMe (Just a) b = a
tryMe Nothing b  = b

class Test a where
    type TT a
    doIt :: TT a -> a -> a

instance Test Int where
    type TT Int = Maybe Int
    doIt (Just a) b  = a
    doIt (Nothing) b = b
```

This works

```
main = putStrLn $ show $ tryMe (Just 2) 25
```

This doesn't

```
main = putStrLn $ show $ doIt (Just 2) 25
{- 
  • Couldn't match expected type ‘TT a0’ with actual type ‘Maybe a1’
  The type variables ‘a0’, ‘a1’ are ambiguous
-}
```

But then, if I specify the type for the second argument it does work

```
main = putStrLn $ show $ doIt (Just 2) 25::Int
```

The type signature for both functions seem to be the same. Why do I need to annotate the second parameter for the type class function? Also, if I annotate only the first parameter to `Maybe Int` it still doesn't work. Why?

Comment: GHC is worried that someone might define an `instance Test Integer`, in which case the choice of instance will be ambiguous.

Comment: GHC, like many compilers, allows for separate compilation: we can compile each module separately. GHC can not know if, in some module which was not yet compiled, there are another instances for your class. Hence, it would be wrong if it committed to the only instance it can see right now. To tell it that this commitment is correct, we have to constrain out call so it can be related to that instance, only. Since the numeric literal in the second argument could be of any type, we have to make its type explicit.

Comment: You have very subtly asked two entirely different questions ("why do I need a type annotation on this program" and "why does the type annotation not have the same affect when placed on the `Maybe Int` argument"). Answers and commenters seem to have chosen to ignore the 2nd question (perhaps rightfully) so you should probably post a separate question for the 2nd question. The short answer is, [type families aren't injective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866375/why-does-ghc-think-that-this-type-variable-is-not-injective).

Comment: @user2407038, it's possible to work around the second problem with an injective type family or (probably better) by using another type family that "takes the inverse" of the first.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> When do I need to cast types in Haskell?

Only in very obscure, pseudo-dependently-typed settings where the compiler can't proove that two types are equal but you know they are; in this case you can [`unsafeCoerce`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Unsafe-Coerce.html#v:unsafeCoerce) them. (Which is like C++' `reinterpret_cast`, i.e. it completely circumvents the type system and just treats a memory location as if it contains the type you've told it. This is *very* unsafe indeed!)

**However**, that's not what you're talking about here at all. Adding a local signature like `::Int` does *not* perform any cast, it merely *adds a hint* to the type checker. That such a hint is needed shouldn't be surprising: you didn't specify anywhere what `a` is supposed to be; `show` is polymorphic in its input and `doIt` polymorphic in its output. But the compiler must know what it is before it can resolve the associated `TT`; choosing the wrong `a` might lead to completely different behaviour from the intended.

The more surprising thing is, really, that sometimes you *can* omit such signatures. The reason this is possible is that Haskell, and more so GHCi, has [defaulting rules](http://www.alexeyshmalko.com/2014/haskell-defaulting-rules/). When you write e.g. `show 3`, you again have an ambiguous `a` type variable, but GHC recognises that the `Num` constraint can be “naturally” fulfilled by the `Integer` type, so it just takes that pick.
Defaulting rules are handy when quickly evaluating something at the REPL, but they are fiddly to rely on, hence I recommend you *never do it* in a proper program.

Now, that doesn't mean you should always add `:: Int` signatures to any subexpression. It does mean that, as a rule, you should aim for making *function arguments always less polymorphic than the results*. What I mean by that: any local type variables should, if possible, be deducable *from the environment*. Then it's sufficient to specify the type of the *final end result*.

Unfortunately, `show` violates that condition, because its argument is polymorphic with a variable `a` that doesn't appear in the result at all. So this is one of the functions where you don't get around having some signature.

Answer (score 5):

All this discussion is fine, but it hasn't yet been stated explicitly that in Haskell *numeric literals are polymorphic*.  You probably knew that, but may not have realized that it has bearing on this question.  In the expression

```
doIt (Just 2) 25
```

`25` does not have type `Int`, it has type `Num a => a` — that is, its type is just some numeric type, awaiting extra information to pin it down exactly.  And what makes this tricky is that the specific choice might affect the type of the first argument.  Thus amalloy's comment

> GHC is worried that someone might define an `instance Test Integer`, in which case the choice of instance will be ambiguous.

When you give that information — which can come from either the argument or the result type (because of the `a -> a` part of `doIt`'s signature) — by writing either of

```
doIt (Just 2) (25 :: Int)
doIt (Just 2) 25 :: Int   -- N.B. this annotates the type of the whole expression
```

then the specific instance is known.

Note that you do not need type families to produce this behavior.  This is par for the course in typeclass resolution.  The following code will produce the same error for the same reason.

```
class Foo a where
    foo :: a -> a

main = print $ foo 42
```

You might be wondering why this doesn't happen with something like

```
main = print 42
```

which is a good question, that leftroundabout has already addressed. It has to do with Haskell's [defaulting rules](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#default-decls), which are so specialized that I consider them little more than a hack.

Comment: Nice, writing `default ()` into GHCi makes it unable to infer something as simple as `42`, it just throws an error saying that the type is ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

With this expression:

```
putStrLn $ show $ tryMe (Just 2) 25
```

We've got this starting information to work from:

```
putStrLn :: String -> IO ()
show :: Show a => a -> String
tryMe :: Maybe Int -> Int -> Int
Just :: b -> Maybe b
2 :: Num c => c
25 :: Num d => d
```

(where I've used different type variables everywhere, so we can more easily consider them all at once in the same scope)

The job of the type-checker is basically to find types to choose for all of those variables, so and then make sure that the argument and result types line up, and that all the required type class instances exist.

Here we can see that `tryMe` applied to two arguments is going to be an `Int`, so `a` (used as input to `show`) must be `Int`. That requires that there is a `Show Int` instance; indeed there is, so we're done with `a`.

Similarly `tryMe` wants a `Maybe Int` where we have the result of applying `Just`. So `b` must be `Int`, and our use of `Just` is `Int -> Maybe Int`.

`Just` was applied to `2 :: Num c => c`. We've decided it must be applied to an `Int`, so `c` must be `Int`. We can do that if we have `Num Int`, and we do, so `c` is dealt with.

That leaves `25 :: Num d => d`. It's used as the second argument to `tryMe`, which is expecting an `Int`, so `d` must be `Int` (again discharging the `Num` constraint).

Then we just have to make sure all the argument and result types line up, which is pretty obvious. This is mostly rehashing the above since we *made* them line up by choosing the only possible value of the type variables, so I won't get into it in detail.

Now, what's different about this?

```
putStrLn $ show $ doIt (Just 2) 25
```

Well, lets look at all the pieces again:

```
putStrLn :: String -> IO ()
show :: Show a => a -> String
doIt :: Test t => TT t -> t -> t
Just :: b -> Maybe b
2 :: Num c => c
25 :: Num d => d
```

The input to `show` is the result of applying `doIt` to two arguments, so it is `t`. So we know that `a` and `t` are the same type, which means we need `Show t`, but we don't know what `t` is yet so we'll have to come back to that.

The result of applying `Just` is used where we want `TT t`. So we know that `Maybe b` must be `TT t`, and therefore `Just :: _b -> TT t`. I've written `_b` using GHC's [partial type signature syntax](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#partial-type-signatures), because this `_b` is not like the `b` we had before. When we had `Just :: b -> Maybe b` we could pick any type we liked for `b` and `Just` could have that type. But now we need some *specific but unknown* type `_b` such that `TT t` is `Maybe _b`. We don't have enough information to know what that type is yet, because without knowing `t` we don't know which instance's definition of `TT t` we're using.

The argument of `Just` is `2 :: Num c => c`. So we can tell that `c` must also be `_b`, and this also means we're going to need a `Num _b` instance. But since we don't know what `_b` is yet we can't check whether there's a `Num` instance for it. We'll come back to it later.

And finally the `25 :: Num d => d` is used where `doIt` wants a `t`. Okay, so `d` is also `t`, and we need a `Num t` instance. Again, we still don't know what `t` is, so we can't check this.

So all up, we've figured out this:

```
putStrLn :: String -> IO ()
show :: t -> String
doIt :: TT t -> t -> t
Just :: _b -> TT t
2 :: _b
25 :: t
```

And have also these constraints waiting to be solved:

```
Test t, Num t, Num _b, Show t, (Maybe _b) ~ (TT t)
```

(If you haven't seen it before, `~` is how we write a constraint that two type expressions must be the same thing)

And we're stuck. There's nothing further we can figure out here, so GHC is going to report a type error. The particular error message you quoted is complaining that we can't tell that `TT t` and `Maybe _b` are the same (it calls the type variables `a0` and `a1`), since we didn't have enough information to select concrete types for them (they are ambiguous).

If we add some extra type signatures for parts of the expression, we can go further. Adding `25 :: Int`<sup>1</sup> immediately lets us read off that `t` is `Int`. Now we can get somewhere! Lets patch that into the constrints we had yet to solve:

```
Test Int, Num Int, Num _b, Show Int, (Maybe _b) ~ (TT Int)
```

`Num Int` and `Show Int` are obvious and built in. We've got `Test Int` too, and that gives us the definition `TT Int = Maybe Int`. So `(Maybe _b) ~ (Maybe Int)`, and therefore `_b` is `Int` too, which also allows us to discharge that `Num _b` constraint (it's `Num Int` again). And again, it's easy now to verify all the argument and result types match up, since we've filled in all the type variables to concrete types.

But why didn't your other attempt work? Lets go back to as far as we could get with no additional type annotation:

```
putStrLn :: String -> IO ()
show :: t -> String
doIt :: TT t -> t -> t
Just :: _b -> TT t
2 :: _b
25 :: t
```

Also needing to solve these constraints:

```
Test t, Num t, Num _b, Show t, (Maybe _b) ~ (TT t)
```

Then add `Just 2 :: Maybe Int`. Since we know that's also `Maybe _b` and also `TT t`, this tells us that `_b` is `Int`. We also now know we're looking for a `Test` instance that gives us `TT t = Maybe Int`. But that doesn't actually determine what `t` is! It's possible that there could also be:

```
instance Test Double where
    type TT Double = Maybe Int
    doIt (Just a) _ = fromIntegral a
    doIt Nothing b = b
```

Now it would be valid to choose `t` as either `Int` or `Double`; either would work fine with your code (since the `25` could also be a `Double`), but would print different things!

It's tempting to complain that because there's only one instance for `t` where `TT t = Maybe Int` that we should choose that one. But the instance selection logic is defined not to guess this way. If you're in a situation where it's *possible* that another matching instance should exist, but isn't there due to an error in the code (forgot to import the module where it's defined, for example), then it doesn't commit to the only matching instance it can see. It only chooses an instance when it **knows** no other instance could possibly apply.<sup>2</sup>

So the "there's only one instance where `TT t = Maybe Int`" argument doesn't let GHC work backward to settle that `t` could be `Int`.

And in general with type families you can only "work forwards"; if you know the type you're applying a type family to you can tell from that what the resulting type should be, but if you know the resulting type this doesn't identify the input type(s). This is often surprising, since ordinary type constructors **do** let us "work backwards" this way; we used this above to conclude from `Maybe _b = Maybe Int` that `_b = Int`. This only works because with new `data` declarations, applying the type constructor always preserves the argument type in the resulting type (e.g. when we apply `Maybe` to `Int`, the resulting type is `Maybe Int`). The same logic doesn't work with type families, because there could be multiple type family instances mapping to the same type, and even when there isn't there is no requirement that there's an identifiable pattern connecting something in the resulting type to the input type (I could have `type TT Char = Maybe (Int -> Double, Bool)`.

So you'll often find that when you need to add a type annotation, you'll often find that adding one in a place whose type is the result of a type family doesn't work, and you'll need to pin down the input to the type family instead (or something else that is required to be the same type as it).

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that the line you quoted as working in your question `main = putStrLn $ show $ doIt (Just 2) 25::Int` does not actually work. The `:: Int` signature binds "as far out as possible", so you're actually claiming that the entire expression `putStrLn $ show $ doIt (Just 2) 25` is of type `Int`, when it must be of type `IO ()`. I'm assuming when you really checked it you put brackets around `25 :: Int`, so `putStrLn $ show $ doIt (Just 2) (25 :: Int)`.

<sup>2</sup> There are specific rules about what GHC considers "certain knowledge" that there could not possibly be any other matching instances. I won't get into them in detail, but basically when you have `instance Constraints a => SomeClass (T a)`, it has to be able to unambiguously pick an instance only by considering the `SomeClass (T a)` bit; it can't look at the constraints left of the `=>` arrow.